# Unable to grab files inside folders on SharePoint using PnP js

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, ajax, pnp

Does anyone have some reference on why I'm unable to pull in files from a folder in SharePoint?

This is what I have so far, this will be my PnP js call (I don't I'm not doing something right)
[image]

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $pnp.setup({
        baseUrl: "https://fh126cloud.sharepoint.com/bdm/business-development/"
    });

    var folderUrl = 'https://fh126cloud.sharepoint.com/bdm/business-development/';

    let getFiles = (folderUrl) => {
        $pnp.sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl).expand("Folders, Files").get().(r => {
        r.Folders.forEach(item => {
            getFiles(item.ServerRelativeUrl);
        });
        r.Files.forEach(item => { 
            console.log(item.ServerRelativeUrl); 
            }) 
        }); 
        var $table = linkModal(items);
        $('#' + id).html($table);
    });

    function linkModal(items) {
        var table = $('');
        items.forEach(item => {
            table.append(`<tr>`);
            table.append(`<td>${item.Name}</td>`);
            table.append(`<tr/>`);
            table.append(`</tbody>`);
        });
        return table;
    }
    getFiles("/Style Library");
});
</script>
```

I'm wanting it placed in this modal between the "modal3body" tags:

```
<div id="modal3" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><div id="x">&times;</div></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Acuvue</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="modal3body">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

All help would be appreciated, I just don't know where I'm making the mistake.

Comment: can you try it as `$pnp.sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl).expand("Folders, Files").get().then().(r => { ` and check ?

Comment: I tried that and didn't get much results sadly.

Comment: can you also change the calling function to `getFiles("/bdm/business-development/Style Library");` and try ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
Items = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/"+ListName+"/"+folderName).files.get();
```